Voiced plosive consonants pronunciation
Listening to readings by native Japanese speakers, I hear in some cases that the voiced consonants are pronounced almost like the analogous voiceless ones (for example にがて だ sounds almost like にがて た).Does it depend on the speaker?
Does it depend on the proximity of the preceding て which, by consonant harmony, makes だ like た;or else a "t" plus "d" in a close speech sequence can be tricky to utter fast?

Could you share your native language, if you don't mind? What I can say at this point is that native speakers always hear it as "da".

Personally I have not heard devoicing of だ, but I sometimes heard word-initial (or sentence-initial) devoicing. Maybe there is some phenomenon with voiceless or only partially voiced pronunciation of theoretically voiced consonants in speech of some Japanese...

This is more a comment to Ody rather than a real answer but, for sake of precision, I was too lengthy.
"I completely agree with you regarding the different phonetic renditions of voiceless versus voiced plosives across languages. Personally, I find it kind of difficult to catch the voiced labial 'b' in languages like German (though this difficulty arises only with certain German speakers). Even the 'b' sound in Spanish differs from the Italian one, despite the close relationship between the two languages. I don't think this is the case between Italian and Japanese. From what I usually hear, the sounds align perfectly, at least regarding k/g and t/d plosives. That's why I questioned the community's opinion—especially the bogowasha's —upon the rare occasions when I’ve experienced confusion between voiced and voiceless sounds. My comment came across as too categorical, as it was a reaction to some responses that quickly dismissed and overlooked my question, claiming that this issue doesn’t exist or that my language lacks sensitivity to such sound distinctions. I wanted to clarify that this is not the case. In consideration of the very low number of cases I stumbled into, I tentatively guessed a sort of allophonic phonetic realization of these sounds in some Japanese speakers. But as everyone excluded it, I finally concluded that the electronic sound reproduction could be the problem. In fact, I have never spoken to Japanese people in Japanese but a few times in English. One word was Japanese though, the personal name of the fellow himself. His name was Daichi, and it sounded identical to the italian pronunciation of "da". Strange enough, 大地 has two possible readings, タイチ and ダイチ so I am not sure whether I misheard the voiceless plosive of his name or I rightly caught the voiced sound.

Right, I don't doubt that there's great overlap between Japanese and Italian phonetics in this department, but there's still room for a bit of potential discrepancy (think of a Venn diagram where two sets almost completely intersect). This would be consistent with the low # of datapoints; this discrepancy would only be perceptible in edge-case pronunciations of /d/ (where the speaker for some reason happens to realise the consonant very close to the JP boundary between voiced and voiceless, and past the IT boundary).

This isn't to rule out audio quality (or maybe even misspeaking/aberrant pronunciation) as a potential problem, by the way. I'm just offering this as an alternative possibility. Given the lack of samples from your end, there's no way to draw a definitive conclusion here. If you want to actually diagnose the issue, post audio clips where a should-be voiced stop sounds voiceless to you, and see if natives feel the same (if they do it's the audio, if they don't it's your perception of it).

I will post audio samples as you suggest.,
as long as I find  some new, which, as ialso

As an Italian I share with Japanese people a perfect awareness of the distinction of voiced versus voiceless plosive consonants. I might have discovered that my problems may simply be connected to bad sound quality of the language teaching sites. I have found other people claiming the same problems as I have. See

Be careful with assumptions like "as a speaker of , I share perfect awareness of ABC distinction with the Japanese". The voiced/voiceless distinction for stops is not made in the exact same way across languages. There are differences in aspiration and voice onset time, and it may be possible for something that registers as "voiced" in a Japanese brain to register as "voiceless" in yours. Take this as a guess, but your observation might be a set of mishearings that stem from aspiration or breathy phonation (or maybe late VOT) on the だ making it count as voiceless to Italian ears.

I will post audio samples as you suggest, as long as I have found  new ones, though, as I mentioned, that's fortunately very rare. Yet, I want to try a different tack also. Since my misperception is almost restricted to the audio files of a specific App, I will enquire the app-designer and the app-forum, to see if they have reported similar sound confusion.
